# SVCS Configuration in Keil Uvision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, keil

I have tried to generate SVCS configuration for Keil project which is located at SVN directory X:\Y\Z. But it fails, no reason for the fail. This is my first time to configure SVCS.

Is there anyone does it for SVN to share an example?

I saw an example for git which shown in the link below.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/kan279/latest/

I have tried the following configuration. No response for this configuration. Any help is appreciated.

[SVCS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX5eO.png)

Thanks.